# Return value inside unbuffer command

Tags: bash, exit-status

I have the following bash code to capture the result of a build while printing the output to the screen and provide parsing of the build results.

```
output=$(unbuffer cmake ... | tee /dev/tty)
parseErrors ${output}
```

parseErrors does what it sounds like. It parses the output for anything that looks like an error. I can exit there, but would rather do it after the function call. How do I get the return status from the cmake build passed to the unbuffer command? I have tried using PIPESTATUS[0], but I think that is returning the value from unbuffer itself.

Comment: I'm not able to understand what you want to achieve. Maybe  you want to get the errors produced by `unbuffer cmake ...` and pass them to `parseErrors` function?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, the errors produced by cmake that is wrapped by the unbuffer call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to have access to the return code from `cmake` after the 2 lines, you can do

```bash
output=$(unbuffer cmake ... | tee /dev/tty; exit "${PIPESTATUS[0]}")
rc=$?
parseErrors ${output}
exit "$rc"
```

The use of PIPESTATUS has to be in the `$()` subshell.
If you just want to add the return code to the output, replace the `exit` by an `echo`.